# Building a multi page serverless application using AWS Lambdas Serverless application model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am new to the serverless application model for the web and want to understand a few things. I went through the AWS Building your first serverless tutorial and have a couple of questions. I am used to the MVC model of LEMP or using .NET.

1. In the tutorial all the pages that were accessed were static html like app.com/login.html and app.com/ride.html. Is this the way things are done in the serverless world? I get it that the lamdba and rest api add the dynamic content.
2. How do I name the pages in my browser to go from app.com/ride.html to app.com/ride-to-london instead?
3. Is Lamdba essentially like just writing Node.js?
4. Is there a way if they are all individual html pages to make one global layout? Any layout template advice would be helpful.
5. I want a multi page application like say this site vs Gmail (less ajaxy) and more like a blog. How is this accomplished? A tutorial on this would be helfpul.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) you can use a modern front end framework like Angular, React, Vue, etc. and host your website statically on S3. Check 
[Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) for more info. Your static website will then interact via HTTP with API Gateway. You then map your lambda functions to events from API Gateway. Check this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)

2) depends on how the framework chosen on step 1) deals with it

3) it can be NodeJS, Go, Python and other supported languages if you wish. Each microservice (lambda function) can be written in a separate language. For more info, see the supported languages at
[Lambda FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

4) again, depends on the framework of your choice

5) this you’ll have to lookup for yourself, but anything like "Blog Tutorial in {Framework of Choice} should do it. Here's an [example](https://codeburst.io/build-a-blog-using-gatsby-js-react-8561bfe8fc91) using React

Let's now say you have deployed your application, you can then make use of other [Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html) supported by AWS. Since you're creating a Blog example, you may want to upload pictures to your Post itself so it looks fancy, but you don't want users on mobile phones to load these high resolution pictures when they are only browsing through your Blog, so you could make use of an S3 Event to generate a thumbnail for your picture, so they can have a preview before actually clicking to see the content. The possibilities are endless.

Using a Serverless model to create applications also enables building event-driven applications out of the box. These applications are highly available and auto-scalable by default.

Comment: Going the serverless way and using Vue.

Comment: On point 1, I was recently asked why we don't serve up static content via a Lambda. Clearly, I could write a lambda that would just take a URL and pass it through, but that seemed ... weird to me, but would it be a way to make the static content scale?

Comment: That's a good point, @J.Gwinner. I suggest you take a look into this thread as it covers off your question nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376491/why-shouldnt-i-use-s3-instead-lambda-for-static-content